# Datetime Add/Subtract Miscalculation

Tags: php, datetime, date-arithmetic, dateinterval

```
$datenow    = new DateTime();
$dn = $datenow -> format("Y-m-d"); //2014-12-02
$yesterday  = $datenow -> sub(new DateInterval('P1D')) -> format("Y-m-d"); //2014-12-01
$yestertwo  = $datenow -> sub(new DateInterval('P2D')) -> format("Y-m-d"); //2014-11-29
$tomorrow   = $datenow -> add(new DateInterval('P1D')) -> format("Y-m-d"); //2014-11-30
$tomotwo    = $datenow -> add(new DateInterval('P2D')) -> format("Y-m-d"); //2014-12-02
```

I had to be missing something here. Date calculation seems to be off.

Update:

```
$datenow            = new DateTime();
$dn            = $datenow -> format("Y-m-d");
$yesterday     = $datenow -> sub(new DateInterval('P1D')) -> format("Y-m-d");
$yestertwo     = $datenow -> sub(new DateInterval('P1D')) -> format("Y-m-d");
$tomorrow      = $datenow -> add(new DateInterval('P3D')) -> format("Y-m-d");
$tomotwo       = $datenow -> add(new DateInterval('P1D')) -> format("Y-m-d");
```

This outputs the correct date now. However, it looks kind of messy and unreadable at first glance. Any solutions?

Comment: Not really.. You just keep calculating with the recalculated date all the time..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're **modifying** `$datenow` each time you `sub`/`add`, so you're essentially changing what "today" means.

Comment: @HDKT: Use `DateTimeImmutable` instead of `DateTime` and things _will_ go the way you expect.

Comment: @Evert You should post that as an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As @ceejayoz mentioned, when you call `add` or `sub` on a `DateTime` object, you also modify it.

Since PHP 5.5 there's a new class: `DateTimeImmutable`. This class has methods like `add` and `sub` as well, but instead of modifying the original, it just returns a new object with the modification applied.

Replace `$datenow = new DateTime();` with `$datenow = new DateTimeImmutable();` and things should just start working.

Comment: For php < 5.5 use `$dateclone = clone $datenow` to clone it, and then modify cloned object.

Comment: I also tried the clone method but DateTimeImmutable works better for me. The added one line of code is a deal breaker for me.